# Hide an element within the Header for the first page

Tags: birt

[I am using BIRT 4.8 and I am trying to hide an element on the header for the first page only. when it comes to second and third pages, I want it to exist. What is the "if, then" code for this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwMBI.png)

I used this code "if (pageNumber == 1){ this.getStyle().display = "none";}" it works on the BIRT 4.8 end but when I generate it on the client end, it does not show up at its entirety for pages 2 and beyond

I also used other codes
this.getStyle().display = (pageNumber == 1) ? "none" : "block"; in the "Render On" & row["**rownum**"] == 1 in the visibility and still no luck.